# Basic queries about cookies

Tags: php, cookies

This might be a silly question but I am learning web development and reached at cookies now. I read about cookies and got the basic understanding of cookies and how to create them and retrieve them.    what I do not understand is:

1. Do we need to create a cookie for each webpage for example in my website i have 5 pages so should i place the cookie only in index page and set the path "/" and it will work for all the pages.
2. To store the information retrieved via cookie for further analysis should I create a database to store each cookie data.

Comment: A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too.Storing the cookie data in the database is all upto you.

Comment: Individual cookies for particular pages or sections of a website can be useful but in general simply using `'/'` for the path makes things easier.

Comment: Thank you for your response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need to create a cookie for each webpage for example in my
>   website i have 5 pages so should i place the cookie only in index page
>   and set the path "/" and it will work for all the pages.

No need to create multiple cookies. You can access same cookie across your webpages, if setting it at root.

> To store the information retrieved via cookie for further analysis
>   should I create a database to store each cookie data.

Why ? It will be stored in user's machine. And why do you want to store it in database. All the user's information will be available in your same database.

Comment: @pgill Always consider accepting answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

The path variable on a cookie simply marks access.

You're assumption about only setting the / is correct if you want that cookie visible throughout all your pages.

If you want to restrict access to that cookie say to an admin page then setting the path to /admin would be fine here.